# cmake-gui from ubuntu terminal on Ubuntu displays:QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, cygwin

I am trying to display gui from ubuntu terminal on windows. But when I run cmake-gui: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted (core dumped).

I also installed cygwin and opened the server using startxwin, but it didn't help. Still same message is coming out.

Comment: opened the server how ? Please clarify how you are doing the things as command and what is the error. Before running cmake-gui you should just use a standard app like xterm for verifying the connection

Comment: Additional, see https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html